# Alignment Gets changed in tabular environment on adding argument in lua function on compiling with LuaLaTeX

Tags: tables, luatex, lua, luacode, directlua

The following code works and gives expected output with expected alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function myfunc()
  str2=[[$1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$  \\  $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ \\  $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ ]]
return (str2)
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\luaTest{\directlua{tex.sprint(myfunc())}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
\luaTest
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

However, the following code doesn't work. The alignment of last entry in last column i.e. entry 5 gets changed. It is slightly shifted towards left. See attached image for this. Here there is no role of adding argument to the function in this code.  However, I am having the same trouble while working with some other code where a function is having some argument[image]. Why this happens? How can it be resolved?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function myfunc(n)
  str2=[[$1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$  \\  $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ \\  $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ ]]
return (str2)
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\luaTest[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(myfunc(#1))}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
\luaTest{9} 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove space after last entry in the `luacode` definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function myfunc(n)
  str2=[[$1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ \\  
         $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ \\  
         $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$]]   % <---
return (str2)
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\luaTest[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(myfunc(#1))}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
\luaTest{9}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or write it as

```
\begin{luacode}
function myfunc(n)
  str2=[[$1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ \\  
         $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ \\  
         $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$%    % <---
       ]]
return (str2)
end
\end{luacode}
```

Comment: Is it possible in definition of new command? `\newcommand\luaTest[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(myfunc(#1))}}%` Something similar to this. Or with no expand string or `\luaNstring` in `luacode*` etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The line ending after `\luaTest{9}` gets interpreted as a space, therefore you get `5`  in the last cell. This gets right aligned correctly, but since the space isn't visible it doesn't look aligned. Write `\luaTest{9}%` to avoid this by commenting the newline/space.

The issue does not appear without the argument since TeX ignores spaces directly after control sequences (like `\luaTest`)

Comment: Can it be done in Lua code itself i.e. in `\begin{luacode} ... \end{luacode}` while defining command `\luaTest`? That is what I am seeking for.